# Remove numbers only if they have more than two digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I would like to remove all numbers that have more than 2 digits. What is the best way to do this in pandas?

```py
   customerId                            text
0           1  Hello you should call 46232348
1           2                      What is 42
2           3       Is this a number or 23213
3           4               1 person is there
4           5                    It is 4x4 cm
```

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "text": ["Hello you should call 46232348",
             "What is 42",
             "Is this a number or 23213",
             '1 person is there',
             'It is 4x4 cm'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
df['text_without_number'] = df['text'].str.replace('\d+', '')

print(df)
```

What I got

```py
   customerId                            text     text_without_number
0           1  Hello you should call 46232348  Hello you should call 
1           2                      What is 42                What is 
2           3       Is this a number or 23213    Is this a number or 
3           4               1 person is there         person is there
4           5                    It is 4x4 cm              It is x cm
```

What I want

```py
   customerId                            text     text_without_number
0           1  Hello you should call 46232348  Hello you should call 
1           2                      What is 42             What is 42  
2           3       Is this a number or 23213    Is this a number or 
3           4               1 person is there      1 person is there
4           5                    It is 4x4 cm           It is 4x4 cm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\d{3,}` to get 3 or more digits:

```
df['text_without_number'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'\s*\d{3,}', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   customerId                            text    text_without_number
0           1  Hello you should call 46232348  Hello you should call
1           2                      What is 42             What is 42
2           3       Is this a number or 23213    Is this a number or
3           4               1 person is there      1 person is there
4           5                    It is 4x4 cm           It is 4x4 cm
```